# Find the minimum weighted path that crosses all vertex

Tags: graph-algorithm

Given a set of vertexes and its corresponding axis, find a path that crosses all vertex with minimum weight where the weight is the total travel distance of the path. you may select whichever vertex you would like to as the starting point of the path.

I was given this question during my online assessment and can't figure out where to approach. Dijkstra's algorithm can be a potential fit to that question, however, this question doesn't have a fixed start and end point, and while finding the lowest cost path, we also need to reach all vertexes.

Comment: Sounds like a Travelling Salesman Problem. I'd start my research there.

Comment: What’s an “axis”?  Sounds like you want a Hamiltonian path.